# Determine template from extension

Tags: templates, add-on-development, structure, plugin, extension

Is there a good way to determine which page template was loaded for a given URI? I'd like to be able to use this information from an add-on.

For example, if my root template group is `home` and the user visits `/`, I want to see that `home/index` is being used. If the user visits `/foo`, does EE expose information about whether it has loaded `home/foo` or `foo/index` or something else?

When using Structure, I can check for a global variable named `structure:page:template_id`, and if that exists, I can easily query for that template. But if Structure isn't in use, I can't find a good way to determine which template is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use another hook, [template_fetch_template](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/template/index.html#id1), and cache the template_id there:

```
public function template_fetch_template($row)
{
  if ( ! ee()->session->cache('your_extension', 'template_id'))
  {
    ee()->session->set_cache('your_extension', 'template_id', $row['template_id']);
  }
}

public function some_other_hook()
{
  $template_id = ee()->session->cache('your_extension', 'template_id');

  //do stuff here with your template_id
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I literally just saw this plugin on twitter this morning: [Template Info](https://github.com/seandelaney/Template_Info), which was originally developed by Leevi Graham for EE1, and then Sean ported to EE2.

Just add one or all of the following tags to your template:

```
{exp:template_info attribute="template_id"}
{exp:template_info attribute="template_name"}
{exp:template_info attribute="template_group_id"}
{exp:template_info attribute="template_group_name"}
```